# Failed To open Database in Android (Pre-Creating)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have put my sqlite database file in the "assets" folder And i write a DataManager class to get data from database,But I am Getting RunTime Error .. I used Debug tool to see where exactly I got to know at `CreateDataBase()` Error Raised .. Please Help me Sombody to fix the issue

This is My Datamanager class . I am precreating database for android but i m getting file not found exception please Help me ..I have showed my Logcat Below .

**(DATAMANAGER Class)**

```
package com.example.applicationdatabase;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    //data/data/ and /databases remain the same always. The one that must be changed is com.example which represents
    //the MAIN package of your project
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.applicationdatabase/databases";

    //the name of your database
    private static String DB_NAME = "database";

    private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    private static DataBaseManager sInstance = null;
    // database version    
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     */
    private DataBaseManager() {
        super(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        try {
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Singleton for DataBase
     *
     * @return singleton instance
     */
    public static DataBaseManager instance() {

        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DataBaseManager();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }


    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
     */
    private void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method an empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {    copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database doesn't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput =ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Select method
     *
     * @param query select query
     * @return - Cursor with the results
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
        return mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    /**
     * Insert method
     *
     * @param table  - name of the table
     * @param values values to insert
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public void insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
        mDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param table - table name
     * @param where WHERE clause, if pass null, all the rows will be deleted
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public void delete(String table, String where) throws SQLException {

        mDataBase.delete(table, where, null);

    }

    /**
     * Update method
     *
     * @param table  - table name
     * @param values - values to update
     * @param where  - WHERE clause, if pass null, all rows will be updated
     */
    public void update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {

        mDataBase.update(table, values, where, null);

    }

    /**
     * Let you make a raw query
     *
     * @param command - the sql comand you want to run
     */
    public void sqlCommand(String command) {
        mDataBase.execSQL(command);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
11-30 16:02:18.908: E/SQLiteLog(968): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
11-30 16:02:18.938: E/SQLiteLog(968): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.applicationdatabase/databasesdatabase) - 
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.applicationdatabase/databasesdatabase'.
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.checkDataBase(DataBaseManager.java:102)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.createDataBase(DataBaseManager.java:69)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.<init>(DataBaseManager.java:39)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.instance(DataBaseManager.java:55)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DBActivity.onCreate(DBActivity.java:35)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-30 16:02:18.948: E/SQLiteDatabase(968):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.applicationdatabase/com.example.applicationdatabase.DBActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.createDataBase(DataBaseManager.java:79)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.<init>(DataBaseManager.java:39)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DataBaseManager.instance(DataBaseManager.java:55)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.applicationdatabase.DBActivity.onCreate(DBActivity.java:35)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-30 16:02:19.008: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you getting any other error messages?

Comment: hi socailrel <br> No Whatever the error was in logcat i have displayed.. I have found that the exception is raised at CreateDataBase() i found it by debugging .. This is my logcat <br>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code which is reading database from Assest Folder. The Only problem was with the PATH which it was Unable to find.

I Hope it may help Someone, if any queries please mesage me...

```
package net.learn2develop.Databases;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabasesActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private Button insertButton;
    private Button updateButton;
    private Button deleteButton;
    private Button displayButton;
    boolean status = false;

    private EditText name;
    private EditText email;
    protected int value1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DBAdapter myDbHelper = new DBAdapter(null);
        myDbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);

        insertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
        updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        displayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_email);

        // --- inserting ------
        insertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (name.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please Enter Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                }
                else if (email.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                }
                else

                    insertRecord();
            }
        });

        // --------Deleting the Records -----------
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteRecord();
            }
        });

        // --- Displaying the Records -------
        displayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DisplayRecord();
            }
        });

        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (name.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please Enter Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                }
                else if (email.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    updateRecord();
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

    }

    protected void DisplayRecord() {
        DBAdapter myDbHelper1 = new DBAdapter(null);
        myDbHelper1.openDataBase();
        Cursor c = myDbHelper1.getAllContacts();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DisplayContact(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        myDbHelper1.close();
    }

    protected void updateRecord() {

        String Name = fetchName();
        String Email = fetchEmail();

        DBAdapter myDbHelper1 = new DBAdapter(null);
        myDbHelper1.openDataBase();
        if (myDbHelper1.updateContact(1, Name, Email))
        {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Update Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Update Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        myDbHelper1.close();

    }

    protected void deleteRecord() {
        DBAdapter myDbHelper1 = new DBAdapter(null);

        myDbHelper1.openDataBase();
        if (myDbHelper1.deleteContact(27))
        {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Delete Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Delete Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        myDbHelper1.close();

    }

    protected void insertRecord() {
        String Name = fetchName();
        String Email = fetchEmail();

        DBAdapter myDbHelper1 = new DBAdapter(null);
        myDbHelper1.openDataBase();
        long id = myDbHelper1.insertContact(Name, Email);
        myDbHelper1.close();
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Record: " + id + " Successfully inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
        name.setText("");
        email.setText("");

    }

    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Name: " + c.getString(1)
                        + "\n" + "Email: " + c.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    public String fetchName()
    {
        String Name = name.getText().trim().toString();
        if (Name.contentEquals(name.getHint()))
        {

            return " ";
        }
        else
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    public String fetchEmail()
    {
        String Email = email.getText().trim().toString();
        if (Email.contentEquals(email.getHint()))
        {
            return " ";
        }
        else
        {
            return Email;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is there from HoneyComb, for earlier versions we don't have problem. Move the code from onCreate() Method to onResume() method and use AsyncTasck to do data base operations. I hope this will solve the problem. 
Or else simply write data base creation statements (SQL staements) either in DataBaseManager or put the sql queries in any xml (inside raw folder)file and process the xml file to create Database.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";

    protected Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sqlStatement;
        try {
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mydbqueries);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                sqlStatement = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                db.execSQL(sqlStatement);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
    }

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = null;
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException
    {
        sqliteDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqliteDB;
    }
}
```

### mydbqueries.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> -->
<!-- database queries -->
<sql>
<!-- Meta data table -->
<!-- <statement> CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 
    'en_US') </statement> Meta data table <statement> INSERT INTO "android_metadata" 
    VALUES('en_US') </statement> -->

<statement>
    sql statement
</statement>
</sql>
```

Comment: I am Beginner to android and please suggest me where am wrong ..This is not sdk or version problem...

Comment: instead of copying db file. use directly queries in your database helper class.

Comment: That is working fine directly creating database ...In real-life applications, sometimes it would be more efficient to pre-create the database at design
time rather than run tim

Comment: even if you create db separately and copy it to the filesystem, it will be same. And one more problem is from HoneyComb copying large files will create problem and i tried few solutions to cope with that but couldn't get good solution. So better to put the queries in xml file or in the code. If we put in xml file the advantage is, we can track db changes(change of table structure etc). I have used db copying like you in 2.2 and it worked well from me only problem is honeycomb. Its not that db will be created every time you open the db when using queries in xml file or queries in java class.

Comment: Hey Thanks All Finally Working fine in Jelly Beans... Bundling Database with Application is very important for me...

Comment: When DB already exist for desktop app with 10k++ entries and it is updated by several people monthly then it is much less job use databases from assets.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with you, I know the operation into the cause of this error.Because you did not add the writte permission,you need add the sentence-"" in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

This exception raised when you want to access to database in "/data/data/YOUR-PACKAGE/databases/YOUR-DATABASE" but there is not any database before your accessing. So you have to create your database. But how? before any access you must use below code:

---

```
SQLiteDatabase db;

db = getWritableDatabase();

if (db != null) {
    b.close();
}
copyDatabase();
```